# How do I "revoke" a commit attached to a pull request on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I added an additional commit to an existing pull request of mine on GitHub, like so:
[image]
And now I regret it. Will a `git push origin master --force` on my fork after resetting `HEAD`
remove this commit from the pull request?

Comment: Either this or `git revert` the commit you don't want anymore. The advantage of a revert is that it is part of your history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, force pushes to a branch which has a pull request on it will update the pull request. (I merged some commits on a pull request of mine using this method.) Standard warnings about force pushes (especially when working with others who might have puled) apply. (Note: this is a good reason to do pull requests on a branch dedicated to that pull request!)

Comment: agreed, the ultimate solution to have multiple pull requests is having multiple branches

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this and realized the error of my ways, then wanted to remove the commit, but save the changes. this is what `git reset --soft` is for.  In my case, I just wanted to roll back the last commit (but keep the changes in my working dir) and then force push back to github, so I did

`git reset --soft HEAD~1`

then

`git push origin master -f`

I then completed that pull request, and then re-committed my changes and pushed again, so they would be in a new pull request.